# Constructing generic types without the class/struct constraint

Tags: c#, generics

I've got separate implementations of a generic interface (one for classes, one for structs) and I wish to use a static Create method which handles construction. But I can't figure out how to make the compiler trust me about the correct type constraint. I totally get why it isn't working, but how do I get around this?

```
public interface ISomething<T> { }

internal class SomethingForReferenceTypes<T> 
  : ISomething<T> where T : class { }

internal class SomethingForValueTypes<T>
  : ISomething<T> where T : struct { }

public static class Something
{
  public static ISomething<T> Create<T>()
  {
    bool TIsAReferenceType = IKnowHowToFigureThisOut();
    if (TIsAReferenceType)
      return new SomethingForReferenceTypes<T>(); // ← T is not accepted here.
    else
      return new SomethingForValueTypes<T>(); // ← T is not accepted here.
  }
}
```

Comment: looks like you will need to use reflection to make the generic types and then activate them

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you're going to be able to do this directly, but you could easily use reflection to create the instance:

```
Type openType = TIsAReferenceType 
    ? typeof(SomethingForReferenceTypes<>)
    : typeof(SomethingForValueTypes<>);
Type constructedType = openType.MakeGenericType(typeof(T));
object ret = Activator.CreateInstance(constructedType );
return (ISomething<T>) ret;
```

Comment: Wouldn't the compiler complain about using `T` with the classes similar to the error that was originally getting?

Comment: @Nkosi, yup, it does.

Comment: @Nkosi: Ooh, quite possibly. Doh. Will fix it up.

Comment: @DavidRutten: Sorry about that. Have a try now.

Comment: @JonSkeet, yeah that totally tricked the compiler. That thing is more gullible than my cat. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidRutten: Fear not, it'll still be checked by the runtime. There are some tricks you can pull in some cases, but this is safe :)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is, you can't. You can do this with reflection, but for maximum efficiency you'll need to perform a dynamic dispatch for the static Create method:

```
public static class Something<T>
{
    public static readonly Func<ISomething<T>> Create;
    static Something()
    {
        var name = typeof(T).IsValueType ? "ValueType" : "Reference";
        var method = typeof(Something<T>).GetMethod(name, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
                                         .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T));
        Create = (Func<ISomething<T>>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<ISomething<T>>), null, method);
    }

    static ISomething<T0> Reference<T0>()
        where T0 : class
    {
        return new SomethingForReferenceTypes<T0>();
    }
    static ISomething<T0> ValueType<T0>()
      where T0 : struct
    {
        return new SomethingForValueTypes<T0>();
    }
}
```

Then you can invoke it with any T, via `Something<T>.Create()`. Should be much more efficient than Activator.CreateInstance.

Comment: Interesting approach with the staticness, it might indeed speed up repeated calls.